# I get a "symbol lookup error" when running "dig google.com" in the terminal

Tags: execute-command

I want to run the command `dig google.com` in the terminal, but what I get is this error message:

```
dig: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libisc-9.18.1-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu.so: undefined symbol: uv_sleep
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running a supported Ubuntu release? Which? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me.

> I would start with deleting the obsolete
> copy of libuv from /usr/local.

https://www.mail-archive.com/bind-users@lists.isc.org/msg31063.html